# Passing A Struct array as a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I would like to pass the struct array as an argument of the print function and then acces its members for printing. Why do I get a pointer error when I do not pass any pointers?

in main.c:

```
struct city {
    double longitude;
    double latitute;
    char name[buf_size]; 
};
int numCitToRead = 10;
struct city cities[25];
printCities(&numCitToRead, cities);
```

Note: The Struct array gets initialised in a file parsing function. It is always 25 fields long, but if numCitToRead is 10, Only 10 fields will be filled

```
int printCities(int* t_numCitToRead, struct city t_cities[25]) {

    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < *t_numCitToRead; i++) {
        printf("\n\n\tCity %d: ", i+1);
        printf("\nname:\t\t%s", t_cities[i].name);
        printf("\nlongitude:\t%f", t_cities[i].longitude);
        printf("\nlatitude:\t%f", t_cities[i].latitute);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I hope someone can help me!

Greetings

Comment: The code you show looks fine. Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: "Why do I get a pointer error when I dont apss any pointers?" --> this is not clear to me. Why would the function work without these arguments? Could you explain that with more details and an example?

Comment: Well, I created a minimal example. To my surprise it worked fine. But when I strech the code out in the multiple header and c files in the main project, it refuses to work. Seems like there is some other error

Comment: My crystal ball tells me your error is with the `printf("\nname:\t\t%s", t_cities[i].name);` expecting a terminated string, and the code you posted doesn't provide that. The content of each `city` in `cities` is *indeterminate* if what you say is true (that code is in `main()` and therefore `cities` is automatic rather than static). That said, posting the actual error message and behavior would have been illuminating to this question. You said, *"The Struct array gets initialised in a file parsing function"* - really? You're sure about that? More relevant code.

Comment: can you  post those other errors in your question ?

Comment: It's a really bad plan to pass in things like that by value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the great support and helpful comments and suggestions.

After adjusting a few different things which were pointed out by people in this thread, it finally compiled succesfully.

The things I adjusted were:

- inlcuded the header file to the city struct data type definition in the printFunctions file
- initialized the struct to resolve pointer errors

Thanks for the great feedback and comments / suggestions.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Have modified the code and its working now.
let's try it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct city {
    double longitude;
    double latitute;
    char *name; 
  };

int printCities(int* t_numCitToRead, struct city t_cities[25]) {

    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < *t_numCitToRead; i++) {
    printf("\n\n\tCity %d: ", i+1);
        printf("\nname:\t\t%s", t_cities[i].name);
        printf("\nlongitude:\t%f", t_cities[i].longitude);
        printf("\nlatitude:\t%f", t_cities[i].latitute);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
  int numCitToRead = 10;
  struct city cities[25];
  // create dummy data
  for(int i =1; i<=25; i++)
  {
   cities[i-1].name = "name";
   cities[i-1].longitude =  10 * i;
   cities[i-1].latitute = 10 * 20;
  } 
 printCities(&numCitToRead, cities);
 return 0;
}
```

Thanks!